# How to avoid getting special character and get single quote instead using cheerio ( node.js )

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I have the following lines of code to replace a little content my a static html file:

```
$ = cheerio.load( fs.readFileSync( path_Url ) ); 

$('a').each( ( idx , _e ) => { 

    let guidId = $(_e).attr('href').split('/').pop().split('.')[0],
    keyMessage = guidIdsMaper.get(guidId);
    keyMessage = ( keyMessage !== undefined ) ? keyMessage : ' ( please enter respective keyMessage  ) ';
    $(_e)
        .attr('href' , '#')
        .attr( 'onclick' , `document.location = 'veeva:gotoSlide(${keyMessage}.zip)'` )

});  

let inner_content =  $.html();
fs.writeFileSync( path_Url , inner_content , 'utf8');
```

So initially in my html file my anchor looks like this:

```
<a href="melt://navigatetoitem/RHEU-1218304-0000_html_0002.html">
    <div id="item91263" class="pageItem" alt="Rectangle">&nbsp;</div>
  </a>
```

And as you can see , using the below line of code:

```
$(_e).attr('href' , '#')
     .attr( 'onclick' , `document.location = 'veeva:gotoSlide(${keyMessage}.zip)'` )
```

But using the replacement code i get a couple of special characters for the single quote `'` , so below is the output:

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.location = &apos;veeva:gotoSlide(RHEU-1218304-0000_html_0002.zip)&apos;">
    <div id="item91263" class="pageItem" alt="Rectangle">&#xA0;</div>
  </a>
```

So how do i avoid getting this `&apos;` and get `'` instead ? would it be necessary to use htmlparser2 or something like that , i have tried it and so far have no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can `hack` by `replace` method:

```
$ = cheerio.load( fs.readFileSync( path_Url ) ); 

const SPECIAL_CHAR = '_XXX_'; // define you special string

$('a').each( ( idx , _e ) => { 

    let guidId = $(_e).attr('href').split('/').pop().split('.')[0],
    keyMessage = guidIdsMaper.get(guidId);
    keyMessage = ( keyMessage !== undefined ) ? keyMessage : ' ( please enter respective keyMessage  ) ';
    $(_e)
        .attr('href' , '#')
        .attr( 'onclick' , `document.location =${SPECIAL_CHAR}veeva:gotoSlide(${keyMessage}.zip)${SPECIAL_CHAR}` )

});  

let inner_content =  $.html().replace(new RegExp(SPECIAL_CHAR, 'g'), `'`); // hack you charactors
fs.writeFileSync( path_Url , inner_content , 'utf8');
```